# Reading files of different types in ByteBuffer

Tags: java, file-io

In My java application (fuse file system) I need to read all types of files into ByteBuffer. I did it as below:

```
public int read(final String path, final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset, final FileInfoWrapper info)
    {

    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    try {
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(p);
        buffer.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        return data.length;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but only  *.txt extensions files are read correctly **(I think its because of less size, larger *.txt files are also not read correctly)**. The rest of file types are not correctly read.

These errors are shown by file type specific applications  while opening the files
[image]

It throws these errors while reading files other than *.txt

```
SEVERE: Exception thrown: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:357)
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:336)
org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360.read(SFS_360.java:132)
net.fusejna.LoggedFuseFilesystem$27.invoke(LoggedFuseFilesystem.java:437)
net.fusejna.LoggedFuseFilesystem$27.invoke(LoggedFuseFilesystem.java:433)
net.fusejna.LoggedFuseFilesystem.log(LoggedFuseFilesystem.java:355)
net.fusejna.LoggedFuseFilesystem.read(LoggedFuseFilesystem.java:432)
net.fusejna.FuseFilesystem._read(FuseFilesystem.java:234)
net.fusejna.StructFuseOperations$23.callback(StructFuseOperations.java:260)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:455)
com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:485)
```

And also reading process is very slow.

What is the correct way to read all types of file correctly and at good speed.

**P.S. whatever solution you suggest, reading file into ByteBuffer is must and also must Returns the number of bytes transferred.**

Comment: What do you mean with "not correctly read"? How do you know if a file is read "correctly" or not? All files are just collections of bytes, there's nothing special about text files.

Comment: @Jesper . My application is file system. I have edited my question and added the picture of errors that each file type application pops up while opening file

Comment: Well there's your problem.. `SEVERE: Exception thrown: java.nio.BufferOverflowException` Your input buffer is not enough to accommodate your data. Try reading a large .txt file, same size as those other files, you'll get the same thing.

Comment: Well you can try reading the file in chunks instead of reading it all at once in your buffer because you never know if your buffer is enough to store the entire file or not. This would solve your problem.

Comment: How do you invoke the `read` method? What do you provide as a `buffer` argument?

Comment: @user1071777 and @ 4aRk Kn1gh7. Yes even *.txt files with larger file size are not read correctly. Please help me modify my code to read the files in chunks

Answer (score 1):

Please read the function signature of [what you're trying to implement](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a2a1c6b4ce1845de56863f8b7939501b5).

```
public int read(final String path, final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset, final FileInfoWrapper info)
```

As you can see, there's a `size` and an `offset` argument there. The function is supposed to read `size` number of bytes from the file at most, and supposed to read them from the offset `offset` from the file. The function is not supposed to read everything. The [provided example filesystem](https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna/blob/270a8cf1b5dbbf73721c8c3c29121dfac8f8c5c1/src/main/java/net/fusejna/examples/HelloFS.java#L45) shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileChannel.map()
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29)
This creates a ByteBuffer that is mapped with direct IO to a file. It will not attempt to load everything in one shot, but will give you data as it's needed.

Comment: Can you please modify my code to do the same via FileChannel.map()